# Where can I purchase a mini-vga to HDMI adapter for older macbook pro?

Tags: video, vga-adapter

I have an older macbook pro - purchased in 2006.  Where can I purchase a mini-vga to HDMI adapter so I can watch movies from my macbook pro on my tv?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

VGA is an analog transmission standard, HDMI is a digital transmission standard. It's not just a matter of changing the connector, the signals they carry are fundamentally different.

You could look in to a USB 2.0 -> HDMI adaptor. [Something like the ones on this page](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters). Though how well those work depend largely on the graphics card in your Mac. The older Macs may not have enough horsepower in their graphics chipsets to drive a second display over USB at anything close to a decent resolution to use on a high definition television.

Answer (score 1):

The 2006 Macbook Pro actually has a DVI port. You don't need to use the VGA adapter that was included, but you will need a DVI to HDMI adapter which does not need the signal converted (same signal standard, different connectors). These are cheap at Monoprice (less than $4 for 3')

http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10231&cs_id=1023104&p_id=2661&seq=1&format=2

Answer (score 1):

### DVI

If you indeed have a [2006 MacBook Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#First_generation), then you have a full-size [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) port, in which case you have two options for HDMI output:

- Get a DVI to HDMI [adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041902&p_id=2029&seq=1&format=2) or [cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10231). These are pretty cheap, since they're just passive adapters that convert the physical connections (the HDMI video signal is basically the same as DVI). However this option does not get you audio over HDMI. If you require audio, you can use a separate 3.5mm audio cable with the headphone jack (many TVs have a separate audio-in jack for one HDMI input), or try the second option.
- Get an active [DVI to HDMI converter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011405). These have inputs for sound (either 3.5mm stereo jacks or Toslink, both of which the MBP supports), which will give you audio over HDMI, plus the video signal. This option is more expensive, but may be preferable if you require audio over HDMI.

### Mini-DVI

If you have a [2006 MacBook (non-Pro)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbook), then you have a [mini-DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI) port, in which case your options are:

- Use a [mini-DVI to HDMI adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041912&p_id=4852&seq=1&format=2). This has the same limitations as the full-size adapter as detailed in the first item above.
- Get a [mini-DVI to DVI adapter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041912&p_id=4851&seq=1&format=2) and combine it with the converter listed in the second option above. One more piece to the puzzle, but it should work just fine.

### Mini-VGA

Finally, if you actually do have a [mini-VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-VGA) port, which came on Most [iBooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBook), [G4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G4) and [G5 iMacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G5), [eMacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emac) and the first [12" Powerbook G4](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powerbook_g4/specs/powerbook_g4_867_12.html), then you need to get a [VGA to HDMI converter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011404), and a [mini-VGA to VGA adapter](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=mini-vga&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Amini-vga).